# Whats my worth of stock after I do the following

Tags: financial-literacy

If I buy  H stock at $100 then buy another stock at $200. Will my stock then be worth $150? Please don't take me back to college in the answer. Lol

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. All you've indicated is that you bought $300 worth of stock. Are you trying to understand your cost-basis and current gain/loss?

Comment: I agree the question is worded confusingly. Simple addition would tell you that if you have $100 in stock and buy $200 more then you have $300 worth of stocks. Not $150.

Comment: Are you talking about more H stock or stock in a different company? Per share prices across companies are generally not comparable.

Comment: The value of your stock is determined by the price for which you could *sell* it, not the price you paid to *buy* it.

Answer (score 4):

> Whats my worth of stock after I do the following

> If I buy H stock at $100 then buy another stock at $200. Will my stock then be worth $150?

Replace "stock" with "precious metal" and maybe the answer will be more clear.

For example, if today, you buy $100 of silver, and $200 of gold, what's the value of your precious metals?  At that moment, it's $300, because you've got $100 of silver and $200 of gold.

It's no different with stocks.  If you buy $100 **worth of shares** of stock in Company A, and $200 **worth of shares** of Company B, then at that moment, you've got $300 total **worth of shares**.

A moment later, **you may not** have $300 **total worth of shares** because the price of shares in Company A might rise or fall, and ditto Company B.

Answer (score 1):

Your cost basis is how much you spent on all shares divided by how many shares you currently have.